A closed subset of separable normed space $X$ is separable.
Let $(X,||\cdot||_X)$ be a normed separable space and let $F$ be a closed subset of $X$, then $F$ is separable.
My attempt
Let $D\subseteq X$ countable and dense, that is $cl_X(D)=X$, then $D\cap F\subseteq F$ is countable. To show that $F$ is separable we must prove that $cl_F(D\cap F)=F$. Now we have
$$cl_F(D\cap F)=cl_X(D\cap F)\cap F\subseteq cl_X(D)\cap cl_X(F)\cap F=X\cap F=F,$$ the we obtained that $cl_F(D\cap F)\subseteq F.$
It remains to prove that $cl_F(D\cap F)\supseteq F.$ We have that $$F=F\cap X=F\cap cl_X(D)\supseteq F\cap cl_X(D\cap F)=cl_F(D\cap F)$$

It's correct?


A normed space is a metric space. For metric spaces, separability and second countability are equivalent. Every subspace of a second countable space is second countable, so every subspace of a separable metric space is separable.
Your attempt is not going to work. For example, let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $F$ be the $x$-axis. Let $D$ be the set of all points with nonzero rational coordinates. Then $D$ is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but $D\cap F$ is empty.

@NingxinThanks! Why $D$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

@NatMath Every open ball contains some point in $D$.
